# How to register a RouterFunction in webflux during runtime, not on startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am building routerFunctions from a source not known during application startup and need a way to register them to be picked up.
What is the correct way to do it in springboot webflux? (I'm using Java 17, springboot 3.1.5)

I've tried it similar to how the **WebFluxConfigurationSupport** does it:

```
@Bean
public RouterFunctionMapping routerFunctionMapping(ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
    RouterFunctionMapping mapping = createRouterFunctionMapping();
    mapping.setOrder(-1);  // go before RequestMappingHandlerMapping
    mapping.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    configureAbstractHandlerMapping(mapping, getPathMatchConfigurer());
    return mapping;
}
```

I've registered the RouterFunctions as beans and tried to recreate the **routerFunctionMapping**, but without success. While debugging, I have confirmed the beans are created and registered in **applicationContext**.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that seems to work:

1. Extend **RouterFunctionMapping** and add a method to rescan RouterFunction beans

```java
public class ReloadableRouterFunctionMapping extends RouterFunctionMapping
{
    /**
     * Rescan application context for RouterFunction beans
     */
    public void reloadFunctionMappings()
    {
        initRouterFunctions();
        if (getRouterFunction() != null)
        {
            RouterFunctions.changeParser(getRouterFunction(), getPathPatternParser());
        }
    }
}
```

2. Extend **WebFluxConfigurationSupport** to create our extended RouterFunctionMapping

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomWebFluxConfigurationSupport extends WebFluxConfigurationSupport
{
    @Override
    protected RouterFunctionMapping createRouterFunctionMapping() 
    {
        return new ReloadableRouterFunctionMapping();
    }

}
```

3. When needed, get the RouterFunctionMapping and call reload method

```java
@Autowired
private RouterFunctionMapping routerFunctionMapping;
...
((ReloadableRouterFunctionMapping)routerFunctionMapping).reloadFunctionMappings();
```